# measurability of solution of a support vector machine

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

The simplest support vector machine solves the following optimisation problem:
$$\min w^Tw \ \text{s.t.} \ y_k(w^Tx_k - b) \geq 1, k=1, \cdots, n,$$
where $(x_k, y_k)$s form our sample with $x_k$ being the characteristic vector and $y_k = \pm 1$ being the class of the $k$th observation.

Assume the above optimisation problem has a unique solution $w^*$ for any given sameple (so all possible samples guarantee a unique solution for SVM). My question is, then can I say $w^*$ is a measurable function of the sample? Or in other words, rigorously, can we call $w^*$ a statistic?

I have searched sbout this question for quite a while, it seems that my question is related to Selection theorem from functional analysis. I haven't learned functional analysis yet so I am not sure and hope to get more insight.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_and_Ryll-Nardzewski_measurable_selection_theorem

Comment: As mentioned above, I am aware of this result from my own research. But I am in lack of knowledge of functional analysis and hope to get more detailed explanantions.

Comment: Maybe this is easier? If a solution for the SVM exists, then $w$ is a vector of constants. A vector of measurable functions is measurable.

Comment: I think you're also mixing plenty of things here. $w^*$ cannot be a statistic, since it's not drawn from the sample, rather $w^*$ is a vector of weights of a *fit* for samples. In SVM we attempt to fit a straight line between clusters of samples.

Comment: But you can also apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_and_Ryll-Nardzewski_measurable_selection_theorem to a vector of constants.

Comment: My description is a bit ambiguous, I will edit it a bit. If we change the sample, then $w^*$ might change as well. If we assume for any given sample, the optimisation problem has a unique solution. Then I can say $w^*$ is a function of the sample. My question asks if this function is measurable.

Comment: If $w^*$ is a measurable function of the sample, then we can call it a statistic, we just don't know the explicit expression of the function.

Comment: Yes I guess you can call it a statistic that way, but it feels a bit odd, because $w^T w$ does not carry a random variable anymore, but is just a constant. To understand the meaning of $w^T w$ necessarily requires looking back to the original function. So in this sense the parameter $w^T w$ and the function are not related. Does $w^T w$ alone summarize the sample? It's like saying $3$ is a statistic of $3x$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an example:

Let your observations be $(-3,-1),(3,1)$.

Then your functions are $-(-3w^T-b)\geq 1$ and $(3w^T-b)\geq 1$.

Take $b=0$ (a plane through origin, reasonable).

We have $3w^T\geq 1$ and $3w^T\geq 1$.

Then smallest such $w^T=1/3$.

Is $w^Tw=1/9$ a summary of our sample (it's not)?